# How to prevent re-rendering of react native ScrollView component onScroll

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-hooks

We are using react native ScrollView containing with different child components(with useMemo) but while scrolling the ScrollView its getting stuck.
We need a smooth scrolling without re-rendering the views.

Can I get some more eyes to look at it with me please:
Thanks in advance.

We have tried Scrollview with less data its working fine but with huge data its getting freeze.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For loading a list of data (huge or not), the recommended way is to use `Flatlist` instead of `ScrollView` in React-Native.

For example:
if this is the data

```js
const data = [
 {id: 0, title: "first element"},
 {id: 1, title: "second element"},
]
```

then you should render it like this:

```js
<Flatlist 
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
  render={({item}) => (
     <Text>{item.title}</Text>
  )}
/>
```

And the reason is that Flatlist doesn't render the data which hasn't been displayed on the screen yet, but ScrollView doesn't have this feature inside it.